# iReport Scriptlet Class Not Found

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've added the jar file to the classpath and confirmed that the class is in there.

I've also included a new scriptlet `scriptlet1` with the intended class `com.marinecyb.hilit2.nbm.gui.export.ScriptletTestsScriptlet`

When I press preview however i get the following error. Any ideas what else I could be doing wrong?

> Error filling print... Error loading scriptlet class : com.marinecyb.hilit2.nbm.gui.export.ScriptletTestsScriptlet 
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading scriptlet class : com.marinecyb.hilit2.nbm.gui.export.ScriptletTestsScriptlet      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:114)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriplets(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:89)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createScriptlets(JRFillDataset.java:502)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:619)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1257)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:928)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.marinecyb.hilit2.nbm.gui.export.ScriptletTestsScriptlet      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)      at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:252)      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:175)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:109)      ... 13 more

Answer (score 1):

Solved: There'd been a maven release so the jar file name had bumped from SNAPSHOT-2.36 to 2.37.